# My laravel-livewire is returning 404 not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-modules

I am designing web application in laravel which I used livewire in a module, but when ever I perform any action in my livewire blade component example `wire:click="action"` its returns `404 NOT FOUND`
My config/modules-livewire.php

```
'custom_modules' => [
        'Chat' => [
            'path' => base_path('libraries/Chat'),
            'module_namespace' => 'Libraries\\Chat',
            // 'namespace' => 'Http\\Livewire',
            // 'view' => 'Resources/views/livewire',
            // 'name_lower' => 'chat',
        ],
    ],
<?php
```

My livewire component codes

```
namespace Modules\Student\Http\Livewire\Pages;
use Livewire\Component;
class RoutineLivewire extends Component
{
    public $test = null;
    public function me($v){
        $this->test = $v;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('student::livewire.pages.routine-livewire');
    }
}
```

My blade code

```
<div>
    <button wire:click="me('ibrahim')">click me</button>
    {{$test}}
     HELLO ROUTINE. 
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have `student::` in front of your view name

Comment: if your view is in the folder `livewire/pages/` just remove the student::   `view('livewire.pages.routine-livewire');`